# How to install rpy2 on colab.research?

Tags: python, r

How to install rpy2 on colab.research.google? I tried the command:

```
pip install rpy2 
import rpy2
```

but it doesn't work. This is the error obtained:

```
Collecting rpy2
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/d1/074ffbbe7b4bf74c60b75d74c8e67a1e4515b0d85f85cd6540e39610754a/rpy2-2.9.5.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command 'R' in the PATH.

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-je87ula0/rpy2/

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-15-93ecdf466471> in <module>()
  1 get_ipython().system('pip install rpy2')
----> 2 import rpy2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpy2'
```

Thanks in advance for your help,
Ines.

Answer (score 0):

Write `!pip install rpy2` instead of `pip install rpy2`

**EDIT**

According to the documentation of rpy2 that can be found [here](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/overview.html):

> Running Rpy2 will require compiled libraries for R, Python, and readline; building rpy2 will require the corresponding development headers (check the documentation for more information about building rpy2).

So, this should work

```
!apt-get install r-base
!pip install rpy2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I tried pip, !pip and also !apt-get without success.

Comment: Here, I've created a notebook and ran the above code successfully!!. You can download the notebook from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qGEIa59A-HwsfriyzymrxERk3yYq5bgs/view).

Answer (score 0):

```
!apt-get install r-base
!pip install rpy2
import rpy2
```

It works ! Thank you Anwarvicc

Comment: Add this to your question, don't add it as an answer!!

Comment: I've added it for you